# Fire OnActionExecuted even if response is returned from OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-web-api, action-filter, actionmethod, onactionexecuting, onactionexecuted

I have following `ActionFilter` attributes implemented for web apis:

1. `LogRequest`: This logs the request and response in `OnActionExecuted` method.
2. `ValidateModel`: This validates the model and returns `BadRequest` by setting `Response` in OnActionExecuting` method.

Now the problem is that - requests for which we have returned `BadRequest` (from `ValidateModel` attribute) are not being logged because `OnActionExecuted` (of `LogRequest` attribute) is not getting fired.

Is there any way I can fire `OnActionExecuted` intentionally?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. 
Some options: 
- depending on your requirements you could implement a message handler for logging purposes.
- don't execute action logic if you model state is not valid and return BadRequest in OnActionExecuted after logging.
- implement a logging function and just call it whereever you need it.
...